# How to insert URL saved in database to URL helper in Laravel view?

Tags: php, laravel

Here's my problem. I fetch the URL/s from the database. For example,

```
{{$items->url}} //this contains the URL
```

In my nav bar, if I hard-coded the link. This works:

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/input') }}">Input/a></li>
```

But I want to insert the variable in the `<a>` tag, but this doesn't work

```
<li><a href="{{ url ('{{$items->url}}') }}">Input</a></li>
```

It always return the error below:

```
syntax error, unexpected '{'
```

Can someone suggest a possible way to print the value of $items->url? Thanks!

Comment: Use this <li><a href="{{ url ($items->url) }}">Input</a></li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ }}` is converted by blade into the php code `<?php echo ?>`. So essentially, you're putting a `<?php` tag inside another `<?php` tag.

What you should do is think that when you have already started one `{{`, and you need some php code inside it, you don't need another. In this case, do this:

```
<li><a href="{{ url($items->url) }}">Input</a></li>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It returns the URL (http://localhost/test/public/$items->url)

Comment: But when I print using {{$items->url}} alone, it returns '/input'

Comment: Please copy it exactly like I wrote it. Notice that I removed the `' '` from your code - they are turning `$items->url` into a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Helpful :

***With Blade***

```
<a href="{{ url('$items->url') }}">Input</a>
```

***Without Blade***

```
<a href="<?php echo url('$items->url') ?>">Input</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!